# Stack allocator and C11's alignment features

Tags: c, memory-management, c11

I am trying to write a custom stack allocator for a game I am working on. To deal with memory alignment, I am using C11's `stdalign.h` header; however, since I do not have prior experience with alignment issues, I'd like a expert opinion on whether I am doing it right.

The majority of the alignment stuff happens in `alignup` and `aligndown` macros. Specifically, in `alignup`, I try to go up to the nearest multiple of `alignof(max_align_t)` (unless we were already a multiple) by shooting past it by adding `alignof(max_align_t) - 1` and then coming back using the bitwise AND. In `aligndown`, I first go below the last multiple of `alignof(max_align_t)` and then come up using `alignup`.

**NOTE:** The stack is in a memory arena and it *grows down* in memory instead of going up.

```
#define alignup(p) ((void*)((((char*)(p)) + (alignof(max_align_t) - 1)) & (~ (alignof(max_align_t) - 1))))

#define aligndown(p) ((void*)(alignup((((char*)(p)) - (alignof(max_align_t) - 1)))))

struct Mem_Stack_Header {
    size_t allocation_size;
    size_t total_size;
};

// This contains the "head" of the stack. The stack grows down, instead of up.
extern void *stack_head;


void* memPush (size_t s)
{
    void *head = stack_head;

    void *mem = (char*)head - s;
    mem = aligndown(mem);

    struct Mem_Stack_Header *h = (struct Mem_Stack_Header*)((char*)mem - sizeof(*h));
    h =  aligndown(h);
    h->allocation_size = s;
    h->total_size = (uintptr_t)((char*)head - (char*)h);

    stack_head = h;

    return mem;
}


void memPop (void)
{
    struct Mem_Stack_Header *h = stack_head;

    stack_head = (char*)stack_head + h->total_size;

    return;
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing this kind of stuff? Any improvements I can make?

Comment: What is `internal_function`? You don't seem to define it anywhere.

Comment: @BenSteffan Oh, that's just `static`. `static` has so many meanings in C, I define `internal_function`, `persistent_value` and `global_variable` to `static` to give some semantic context.

Comment: I see. Besides, are you aware that your code contains *undefined behavior* due to your use of a reserved identifier (`_Mem_Stack_Header` is reserved because it begins with an underscore immediately followed by a capital letter)?

Comment: @BenSteffan No, I thought two underscores were not allowed. Just googled and found out about one underscore at file scope too. Thanks.

Comment: "Is this the correct way of doing this kind of stuff?" No. Code is broken with the first call of `memPush()`and  `void *mem = (char*)head - s;` as that is pointer arithmetic on an invalid pointer (`stack_head == NULL`).  VTC

Comment: @chux Why? Can you give a bit more detail?

Comment: When code calls `memPop (void)` first, `stack_head` has the value of all zero bits (e.g. `NULL`).  So code does `void *head = NULL; void *mem = (char*)NULL - s;`.  The subtraction of `s` from an invalid pointer like `NULL` is UB.

Comment: @chux I didn't wanted to go in full detail but `stack_head` is a pointer that already points to some memory. I'm not gonna increment/decrement in random address space! Program will segfault!

Comment: As `static void *stack_head;`, `stack_head` does not point to random address space.  It is a _null pointer_.  With your edit to `extern void *stack_head;`, `stack_head` could then indeed point to some valid memory.  Best to post the code you have tested.

Comment: This is the 3rd code change since receiving comment feedback and 1st since receiving an answer.  This is not good Code Review etiquette.  Rolling back code.

Comment: See [Do not add an improved version of the code after receiving an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way of doing this kind of stuff? Any improvements I can make?

1. The role of member `allocation_size` is unclear.  It appears to represent the  raw alignment with `h->allocation_size = s;`.  <strike>Later use with `stack_head = (char*)stack_head + h->total_size;` could then result in an unaligned `stack_head`.</strike>  I recommend that `void* memPush (size_t s)` first take `s` and increment it as needed to an aligned size and then save that value in  `allocation_size`.  This will simplify subsequent code too especially the macro `aligndown()`

   ```
   s = (s + alignof(max_align_t) - 1) & ~(alignof(max_align_t) - 1u);
   ```
2. There is no protection against pushing too much.  I'd expect the size of memory available with `stack_head` to be provided and `memPush()` to code against overflow.  In any case, OP should provide documentation concerning what happens when too much memory is requested.
3. There is no clear functionality against popping too much.  I'd expect either an error return or a perhaps the equivalent of the top allocation having size 0.
4. Some compilers will warn about mixed signed/unsigned math. 
   As the return type from `alignof()` is some unsigned type, use unsigned constants throughout.

   ```
   //alignof(max_align_t) - 1
   alignof(max_align_t) - 1u
   ```
5. The *name* `stack_head` is a global object that could easily collide with other code.  Its name does not suggest that is is part of the `memPop(), memPush()` functions.  Recommend a name aligned with the funcitons like `mem_stack_head`.
6. A use of `memPush(0)` needs special consideration.  I recommend that such usage returns the same as `memPush(alignof(max_align_t))` to provide unique allocations.  In any case, OP should provide documentation concerning the special case.
7. `uintptr_t` is an optional type and not the best to use here.  `(char*)head - (char*)h` results in type `ptrdiff_t`, simply cast it to the destination type. 
   Alternative:

   ```
   //h->total_size = (uintptr_t)((char*)head - (char*)h);
   h->total_size = (size_t)((char*)head - (char*)h);
   ```
8. Code could reduce explicit coding of cast `(char *)` by using `char *head = stack_head;`
9. Alternative idea to this line of code:

   ```
   // struct Mem_Stack_Header *h = (struct Mem_Stack_Header*)((char*)mem - sizeof(*h));
   struct Mem_Stack_Header *h = (struct Mem_Stack_Header*)mem - 1;
   ```
10. A simple test harness would help in evaluation of this code.
11. `alignof` is not valid without `#include <stdalign.h>`.  Other include files missing too.

Comment: Regarding 1, `allocation_size` is essentially `requested_size` to track how much memory the client code asked for and would actually use (I've renamed it). `total_size` is the size that includes actual memory allocated and it is used to deallocate (which means it will always be aligned properly since it was assigned to after aligning the pointers).

Comment: WRT 5, ignore issues about `stack_head`, it was added as a placeholder in this code, the actual code uses a `Engine_State` struct which is kind of irrelevant to the question and would just add noise. Thanks for the other points.

Comment: Yes I agree #1 is erroneous with regard to `stack_head = (char*)stack_head + h->total_size;`

Comment: Can you please provide some feedback on whether the `alignup` and `aligndown` macros are correct and whether this is right way to deal with alignment in custom allocators? That's the part of the code that I don't have any experience with and would like to be sure about.

Comment: Aside from #4, I do not see a problem with `aligndown()`.  It appears functionally correct, yet could be simplified. Example the final `(void*)` is not needed.  Further, IMO, it is the wrong approach.  Instead, insure `stack_head` is aligned and adjust `size_t s` to an align multiple.